# Is there an efficient implementation in Python for SAS sql codes that merge two data with inequality condition in matching?

Tags: python, merge, sas, conditional-statements, inequality

I would like to implement in Python the following simple SAS codes that merge two data with inequality condition. The input dataset "indst" has three columns: 'id', 'DATE', 'RET'.
In SAS:

```
*-----------------------------------
proc sql;
   create table ret11 as
   select a.id, a.date, exp(sum(log(1+b.ret)))-1 as ret11
     from indst (where=(year(date)>=1961)) as a, 
          indst (where=(year(date)>=1960)) as b
    where a.id=b.id and 1<=intck('month',b.date,a.date)<=11
    group by a.id, a.date
   having count(b.ret)=11
    order by a.date, a.id;
quit;  
*-----------------------------------
```

My current Python implementation is:

```
#-----------------------------------
indst_post1960=indst.loc[indst['DATE'].dt.year>=1960, ['id', 'DATE', 'RET']].rename(columns={'DATE' : 'DATE1'})
indst_post1960['logGrossRET']=np.log(1+indst_post1960.RET)
indst_post1961=indst.loc[indst['DATE'].dt.year>=1961, ['id', 'DATE']]
tmp=pd.merge(indst_post1961, indst_post1960, on=['id'], how="inner")
tmp=tmp[(1<=(tmp.DATE.dt.to_period("M")-tmp.DATE1.dt.to_period("M")).apply(attrgetter('n'))) & 
        ((tmp.DATE.dt.to_period("M")-tmp.DATE1.dt.to_period("M")).apply(attrgetter('n'))<=11)]
ret11 = tmp.groupby(['id','DATE'], as_index=False).agg(
        n_RET = ("RET", "count"),
        sum_logGrossRET = ("logGrossRET", "sum")).query('n_RET==11')
ret11['ret11'] = np.exp(ret11.sum_logGrossRET)-1
ret11 = ret11[['id', 'DATE', 'ret11']].sort_values(by=['DATE','id'])
#-----------------------------------
```

The problem is that while the above SAS codes finished the job within 3 minutes, my Python codes ran for a very long time and eventually reported insufficient memory error at the part of pd.merge. I have 64GB ram.

It must be that my Python implementation is not efficient, especially for the data merger with inequality condition. The task I try to implement is pretty common when people use sql to merge two data with some inequality condition, so is there an efficient way to implement it in Python?

Comment: How big are the tables?  How many rows per ID in each year?  How big is the result? You might be creating too large a cartesian join, where the inequality will limit it sufficiently, but without that it's too large.

Comment: That looks like a moving time series type calculation. Instead of rolling your own, have you look at the time series packages to do these types of calculations? Something like Prophet likely has the capabilities? https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/12/6-powerful-feature-engineering-techniques-time-series/

Comment: @Joe: You are right. I understand that my input data size is too large, and my current Python code would run if I used a small input data. But I am surprised by how SAS can efficiently handle the same large size of input data. Hence, my question is that: can I program in Python to achieve a better efficiency than my current codes?

Comment: Your question isn't answerable without the details.  Undoubtedly it's possible - but the details matter.  (And, as Reeza says, find a package that handles this already.)

Comment: @Reeza You are right that my specific example can be efficiently implemented with methods in your link. But my example is just to illustrate my general question which is not confined to moving window time series: in Python, how to code efficiently the merger of two different datasets (i.e., it is not that one dataset is a subset of the other) with inequality conditions, since it can be easily and efficiently implemented in SAS? In my work, I often need to deal with such situation and I hope to have a solution to all the cases in addition to just the case of moving window time series.

Comment: @Joe sure, here are the details: indst_post1960 is [4248573 rows x 3 columns] and indst_post1961 is [4222419 rows x 2 columns], the result "ret11" generated by SAS is [3708830 rows x 3 columns] and I did not get to see the Python result due to error report. Each observation in indst is a month date-by-id. So there are 12 rows per ID each year, corresponding to 12 months in a year.
]